How much current should I expect at 240V on 4/0 wire at 670 feet?
I plan on running aluminum direct burial 4/0 4/0 4/0 2/0 wire to my shop. It's a 670-ft run. I understand there's going to be a large voltage drop. How many reliable amps do I expect to get out of that wire at 670 ft.?
Unfortunately my knowledge and the amount of money I had is what allowed me to get that size wire if I had known better I probably would have upsized. I believe I have about 250 volts at my panel.

There's an important question about fault clearing. You need the breaker to quickly trip if there is a dead short on the far end of the feeder.  Instant trip needs between 600% and 1050% (manufacturing tolerance) of the normal breaker trip. Thermal trip obeys a trip curve, again with a band of manufacturing tolerance.

Southwire is telling me that length of 4/0 is 0.11 ohms and 2/0 is 0.17 ohms.   Both round trip.
So with a 240V dead short, round trip 0.11 ohms, the maximum available fault current will be 2181 amps.
With a 120V bolted fault to ground, round trip 0.14 ohms, the maximum available fault current is 857 amps.
A 100A breaker would instant-trip on a 240V short circuit, and would trip in "instant" through "1 second" on a 120V ground fault. I wouldn't go any higher amp breaker than that.

Using the Southwire Voltage Drop Calculator, 4/0 aluminum, 670', 240V, the maximum to stay under 5% is 76A. That's assuming that your loads can handle 5% (most can) and that most of your loads are 240V loads (EV charging, large motors, etc.). 5% is arbitrary but a reasonable starting point.
